# Учебник по MFC

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что изучал С++ на **С++Builder'e**, сейчас понадобилось программировать в **VisualC++**, те кто знает **С++Builder** поймут, что для создания в нем интерфейса программы знать вообще ничего не нужно, бери и перетаскивай компоненты на форму, однако в **VisualC++** все не так.

Не могли бы вы посоветовать литературу по библиотеке **MFC**, все что я нашел лишь описывает работу с ней, хотелось бы знать более детально из каких конкретно классов она состоит и для чего каждый из них нужен.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: MFC - это устаревшая вещь. Изучайте лучше Qt, GTK или wxWidgets.

Comment: А Qt это же вроде как инструментарий со своим интерфейсом и прочими заморочками, он выходит за рамки Visual C++ скорее дополняя его чем являясь его составляющей) разве не так?)

Comment: GTK по виновс - страшный сон.

Comment: Почему?) Он же как раз содержит библиотеки для Windows System)

Comment: ЧорныйВластелин, они все тянут за собой либы дополнительные, смирись. После Qt поймешь, что MFC - это ад и Израиль))

Comment: MFC в самом деле динозавр, и вам не стоит вообще заниматься этим вопросом. Если строго под виндовс то погружайтесь в технологии NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по каким-то причинам нужно работать с MFC, то самый полный источник информации - это сайт MSDN:

- [MFC Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx)
- [Hierarchy Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws8s10w4(v=vs.100).aspx)

Все - на английском, поскольку MFC - устаревший продукт, и MS не видит смысла переводить документацию. Если нужно на русском, подойдут старые книги, вроде "MFC: основы программирования" Шилдта.